# best opengl shader performance one shader or multi

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

If I want to render many different models which may contains textures of different types like diffuse, specular or normal maps and may contains only colors or mix of them, to get best FPS should I use multi shader program for each case or can I use one shader program and test the condition ?

Comment: Have you tried doing both and comparing the performance?

Comment: yes but in small light models there is no noticeable difference so I ask if some one test in heavy rendering and can help me !

Answer (score -1):

Conditional branches means a slightly slower performance.

In my opinion it's better to use several shaders. The cost of selecting a shader is much more less that conditional execution.

Comment: Shouldn't conditional branches only cost performance if they depend on a non uniform expression?

Comment: yes, I made some researches and read that in many sites and articles